# How to store which child was clicked in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I go about getting which child was clicked when the container is clicked? Whichever child is clicked to store that in a variable?
w
html:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By finding the clicked `div` inside `.cont`

```
$(".cont div").click(function(){
   var clicked = $(this);
})
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vqafdy9u/)

Comment: OP asked for: `getting which child was clicked when the container is clicked?`

Comment: `Whichever child is clicked to store that in a variable` Second line

Comment: It certainly was from the first line, i had to read it twice haha

Answer (score 1):

You can use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

```
$('.cont').on('click',function(e){
  console.log(e.target.nodeName);
  console.log(e.target.className);
});
```